# Bounce area color in UITableView: top and bottom

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

In my table view when I scroll up or down, I see the bounce area that has a different color than my table. Can I set an identical color both in the top and in the bottom? I would like everything to be the same gray.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You must change the view background color

Comment: nope, does not work